# Docker creates a bridge network with name "env_default" when network is not specified

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a spring boot app started using the below docker-compose. It creates a new bridge network with name "env_default" instead of using the default one available.

```
version: "3"

services:
  backend-config:
    image: hub/backend-config:v200
    container_name: backend-config
    expose:
      - 9091
    ports:
      - 9091:9091
    environment:
      - LOG_LOCATION=/var/lib/backend/config/logs
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/var/lib/backend/config/logs
```

Below are the networks after the above container is started. My understanding was container by default will use the default bridge network. Is this the correct behavior?

```
NETWORK ID     NAME          DRIVER    SCOPE
b66610237847   bridge        bridge    local
736cd740d86e   env_default   bridge    local
6ad7ca425e1c   host          host      local
e01327716975   none          null      local
```

Comment: Are you sure docker creates the `env_default` network? Can you do `docker network inspect env_default` to confirm your container is in the network?

Comment: Compose creates a "user-defined bridge network" named `default` automatically.  This is helpful since the legacy "default bridge network" has some limitations and you don't usually want it.  (You can also delete the legacy `expose:` option from your Compose file, it does nothing.)  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Comment: The reason it creates a network per docker-compose is because you might have another compose file with another service called `backend-config` too. By creating separate networks, you can have both compose files running without name clashes.

Comment: @Garuno Yes, the container is in the "env_default" network.  I guess, as David Maze mentioned, docker creates it automatically. I will manually add a properly named bridge network so that I can add all containers also into it.

Comment: I wouldn't bother.  If you have no `networks:` settings at all in the `docker-compose.yml` file then all of the containers will be attached to the Compose-created `default` network, and that should work fine for almost every use case.